# Why is the package size of NPM run bulid inconsistent with the website (React)

Tags: reactjs

I use NPM run bulid to package the website, and the console displays chunk JS is 1.04MB in size, but when I open ifinder locally, the file size is 3.8m. Why?

[png1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOi0R.png
;
[png2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olnqL.png

Comment: Is your question , why we have difference ? or how can we use files after gzip ?

Answer (score 1):

Its file size after gzip, Not actual file size

[image]

Comment: so, How can I use these compressed files to deploy to the server? i want to get after gzip file.

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse it was compressed by gzip. Gzip compresses upto 90% of the file size.

Comment: so, How can I use these compressed files to deploy to the server? i want to get after gzip file.

Comment: Hello , if you want to use this files in the server , read this answers
[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700704/does-create-react-app-provides-gzip-compression-out-of-the-box)
[Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186336/how-to-compress-the-files-using-gzip-in-react-app/67716096#67716096) 
@noneName