# How to compress build files in create react app without ejecting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to figure out how to best optimize my build file and ran across the notion of compressing text files like js and css. From what I've come across every article either assumes you have access to the webpack config file or you've ejected from CRA. I don't want to.

So I added a post build script to my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build --prefix client",
    "prod-compress": "gzip client/build/static/js/*.js && gzip client/build/static/css/*.css",
```

which results in the `/client/build/static/js` and `/client/build/static/css` folders looking like this:

[image]
[image]

I then went into my app.js file and added the following code:

```
app.get('*.js', function(req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    next();
});

app.get('*.css', function(req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    next();
});
```

If I understand what's happening correctly, the f/e `/client/public/index.html` file will still reference a regular `.js` file. However, when the file is requested from the server, it will respond with the `.js.gz` file.

However, when I compress the files the entire site goes blank, like it can't find anything to serve up.
[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704772/how-to-compress-build-with-without-ejecting-create-react-app-also-include-compr

Comment: You can use https://github.com/expressjs/compression#readme this allows your assert to be downloaded as gzip files and you don't have to manually do it like you mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a new dependency, I would recommend using [express-static-gzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip) which will automatically serve your compressed files:

```js
const express = require("express");
const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
const app = express();

const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static');
app.use("/", expressStaticGzip(buildPath);
```

You also have the choice to add other types of compression like brotli by passing an options object:

```js
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static');
  app.use(
    '/',
    expressStaticGzip(buildPath, {
      enableBrotli: true,
      orderPreference: ['br', 'gz']
    })
  );
```

Brotli gives you even more optimized files than gzip but it's not supported by all browsers. Thankfully, express-static-gzip automatically picks the correct file to send based on the `Accept-Encoding/Content-Encoding` header the user's browser sends to it.

If you want to use brotli, I recommend taking a look at [compress-create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-create-react-app). It's specifically made for React apps but should work with any files.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of compress-create-react-app*